# How to assert attributes value using sibling attribute value in hamcrest matcher

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, rest-assured, hamcrest

Given an API response as:

```
{
    "res": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "a",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "b",
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I assert using *hamcrest matcher* that name field for object with id **1** is **a**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be

```
given()...
        .then()
        .body("res.find {it.id == 1}.name", equalTo("a"));
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I was using .body ("res.find {it.id = 1}.name", equalTo("a"));, after seeing your answer I realized my condition symbol is incorrect. So stupid of me, thanks :)